# Using & Understanding Date Values in Form

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to understand and use the values for putting a "date range" in my form.  I want the applicant to put employment range of "from-to". I am not sure what to type in the field. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

I was able to create a form with two date fields that will give the user the ability to enter in starting and ending dates that they worked with an employer. The only calculation that I used was to make the ending date one day after the starting date. This means that you cant select the same date or any date before the selected starting date.

The repeating section will look something like this collecting employer information and starting/ending dates.

[image]

The calculation to keep uses from selecting date from before or on the start date can be entered into the Range value "Minimum" box. I have used the advanced editor so that you can see the complete calculation.

[image]

Once this is done you can preview your form to see the date calculation in action, start by selecting a starting date. When you open the date picker for the ending date you will find that you cant select the same date or any date before the starting date.

[image]